# Vue JS Composition API, call composable async function both in setup and in an event function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vue-composition-api

as "disclaimer" so to speak, kindly note that I'm relatively new to Vue and I am currently developing a data visualisation project, as a means to get acquainted with the concepts.

So, to retrieve the data from an API, I use the following function as a composable.

```
import {ref} from 'vue'
const getData = (endpoint) => {
    const data = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)
    const load = async() => {
      try{
        let response = await fetch("BASE_URL"+endpoint)
        if (!response.ok){
          throw Error('Error when trying to fetch data')
        }
        data.value = await response.json()
      }
      catch (err){
        error.value = err.message
      }
    }
    return{data, error, load}
}
export default getData
```

Now, I retrieve the data from inside the setup function and display them on the template. What I need help with is making another API call after an @click event for example, and updating the data on the page.

My code looks like this below, in which the handleclick function doesn't work as intended. The desired result would be for the template to show data from endpoint2 after clicking the button. I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of some of the concepts, but that's why I ask the community for some help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
    <div>
      <button @click="handleClick">click me</button>
    </div>
    <div>{{data}}</div>
</template>

<script>
import {ref} from 'vue'
import getData from '../composables/getData'

export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  setup(){
    const {data, error, load} = getData('endpoint1')
    load()

    const handleClick = () => {
            console.log('clicked')
            const {data, error, load} = getData('endpoint2')
            load()
        }
    return {data, handleClick}
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can't just `return {data, handleClick}` ... the `button` doesn't know what you want to do with the data!

Comment: the ```return {data, handleClick}``` comes from the setup function back to the template, the handleclick doesn't return something

Comment: Yes. I can read code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getData` is efficiently a composition function (they are conventionally called like `useData` to designate their purpose) but it's used incorrectly.

Composition functions are called directly in setup function/block. Any other usage depends on the implementation and needs to be additionally confirmed. That the function returns refs suggests that refs are supposed to be created once and then ref values are accessed.

It's not a good practice to put asynchronous side effects like `load` to setup. They are usually done on component mount, also lifecycle hooks and event listeners handle errors from promises, while a rejection from `load()` would remain unhandled (probably not the case here because of fail-safe code with `catch`).

Should be:

```
const {data: data1, error: error1, load: load1} = useData('endpoint1')
const {data: data2, error: error2, load: load2} = useData('endpoint2')

onMounted(() => {
  return load1()
})

const handleClick = () => {
  return load2()
}

return {data1,...}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response Estus. I understand your point, but the question is, how would you go about querying endpoint2? If I do something like 
`const handleClick = () => {
            endpoint.value = 'endpoint2'
            return getData(endpoint.value).load()
        }`
I can see from the network tab that there is a request to endpoint2, but is not assigned to any variable/ref

Comment: I missed that it's endpoint1 in one place and endpoint2 in another. They are different hooks and different data sets. You can combine data1, data2 with a computed if there's a good way for that. It's not a very common that the same data is fetched from different endpoints, getData doesn't cover this case. If there's main endpoint and alternative endpoints, you could make `load` accept optional argument to override url

Comment: Thanks Estus, will try to add argument in load, as in my 'real world' project, I would have numerous dataN items. Will try some stuff and post a (successful hopefully) result

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here.

```
const {data, error, load} = getData('endpoint2')
```

This doesn't update the data returned by `setup` function at all, here you just assign variables called ( data, error, load ) and you don't use it.

I think you need to turn your composable function to async one instead of using `load` function.

And then set a `ref` with the initial value with the getData function.

And in the handle click function reset the `ref`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this. You can try to override the reference

```
const handleClick = () => {
        console.log('clicked')
        const {data: scopedData, error, load} = getData('endpoint2')
        data = scopedData();
        load()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to solve my issue, many thanks to everyone for their feedback.

Per @Estus Flask suggestion, I edited my composable, and moved the argument from the getData ref to the load function itself, as below:

```
const getData = () => {
    const data = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)
    const load = async(endpoint) => {
      try{
        let response = await fetch("BASE_URL"+endpoint)
        if (!response.ok){
          throw Error('Error when trying to fetch data')
        }
        data.value = await response.json()
      }
      catch (err){
        error.value = err.message
      }
    }
    return{data, error, load}
}
export default getData
```

and the setup and handleclick function look like this:

```
setup(){
    const endpoint = ref('endpoint1')
    const {data, error, load} = getData()
    load(endpoint.value)

    const handleClick = () => {
            endpoint.value = 'endpoint2'            
            load(endpoint.value)
        }
    return {data, handleClick}
```